# String to List of words

Tags: python

I have a string `a = '["Internet Software","IoT"]'`. It is not a list. It is a **string** of length 27.

I want to convert this into a list containing elements : Internet Software and IoT.

How do I do so?

Comment: if it's a string why haven't you put " or ' around it

Comment: Did you research this at all? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894269/3001761

Answer (score 0):

use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

```
a = '["Internet Software","IoT"]'
lst = eval(a)
print type(lst)
# <type 'list'>
```

Comment: Noo... never use `eval(..)`...

Comment: it seems that his string contains a valid python code, so `eval()` should do the thing. but I agree with @WillemVanOnsem to not use it on unverified strings.

Comment: Ever heard of `ast.literal_eval`? It is a safe `eval` in the sense that it only works for literals, so it will not execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 options: `eval` and `json.loads`

```
import json

a = '["Internet Software","IoT"]'
print(eval(a)) # ['Internet Software', 'IoT']
print(json.loads(a)) # ['Internet Software', 'IoT']
```

I would recommend against `eval`, because it could execute malicious code.

`json.loads` on the other hand only works if your string is valid JSON (which is true for the string you posted).